# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'method' with no type in Linux Mint but not in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linux

I have this constructor in Code::Blocks added as a default setter, which doesn't impede the code from starting and works like a charm in case I ever want to make the program accept user values, yet it doesn't seem to work the same in Linux Mint whenever I try to port it to my VirtualBox, spewing out this error:

```
complejo.h:3:11: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘complejo’ with no type [-fpermissive]
```

I've made sure to look out for typos or other kinds of mistakes, and I'm not really sure how it works for one and not for the other.

Here goes the header file

```
class complejo_t{
public:
complejo();
friend void complejoImprimir(complejo_t &);
friend void complejoCargar(complejo_t*, int, int);
friend complejo_t complejoSumar(complejo_t&, complejo_t&);
friend complejo_t complejoRestar(complejo_t&, complejo_t&);
private:
int x;
int y;
};
```

And the .cpp one that executes that one method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "complejo.h"

using namespace std;

complejo_t::complejo(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

};
```

As always, apologies for the bother and thanks in advance.

Comment: `complejo_t()` is not a proper constructor for a class named `complejo`

Comment: My bad. That's an editing mistake

Comment: They must match. If one toolchain accepts the code and the other does not,  the accepting toolchain is broken.

Comment: Do not edit an answered question to fix the problem. This invalidates the answer. Also do not edit the Question to expand it to include new problems you encountered after fixing the initial problem. Instead try to solve the problem on your own and if you haven't figured it out before the question cool-down timer expires, ask a new Question.

Answer (score 1):

The name of any constructor MUST match the name of its class.

In the example provided, `complejo()` is not a constructor for the `complejo_t` class, it is a separate method instead, and the compiler error is correct that no return type is being specified for it. Some compilers may allow that, assuming `int` is the default type. Don't rely on that behavior.